# Как изменить иконку распознавания голоса?

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

При вызове распознавания голоса появляется посередине стандартная иконка с микрофончиком. Проблема в том, что она загораживает необходимую информацию. Как её уменьшить, убрав белый фон, а также поднять кверху или опустить вниз экрана? Как это сделать нестандартным способом?

Comment: если вы используете стандартный способ, то никак.

Comment: Хм... а не стандартный?

Comment: А какой именно из всех 100 000 нестандартных способов?

Comment: Самый удобный и простой)